# How to combine StaticResource and string to xpath

Tags: wpf, string, xpath, staticresource

I'm trying to figure out  how to combine StaticResource and string to xpath, following is my code：

in App.xaml with a string static StaticResource called "value"

```
<Application.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="value">/value</sys:String>
</Application.Resources>
```

in Window1.xaml there is a combobox reference to StaticResource "value"，also combobox datacontext reference to a xml file：

```
            <ComboBox x:Name="cb01" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168" Height="37" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=town/enum/value}"  IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding XPath=town{StaticResource value}}"/>
```

I wish XPath should be "town/value",but it doesn't work.
How to combine StaticResource and string to xpath.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use `StringFormat` in xaml.

Comment: Write a Converter.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan thanks.But can't use Converter for xpath.

Comment: This may help you...http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/wpf-application/resources/

Comment: @keerti_h thanks.but it can't make it work.